# How to solve "not all divisions are known" error?

Tags: dask

I'm trying to filter a Dask dataframe with `groupby`.

```
df = df.set_index('ngram');
sizes = df.groupby('ngram').size();
df = df[sizes > 15];
```

However, `df.head(15)` throws the error `` ValueError: Not all divisions are known, can't align partitions. Please use `set_index` to set the index. ``. The divisions on `sizes` are not known:

```
>>> df.known_divisions
True
>>> sizes.known_divisions
False
```

A workaround is to do `sizes.compute()` or `.to_csv(...)` and then read it back to Dask with `dd.from_pandas` or `dd.read_csv`. Then `sizes.known_divisions` would return `True`. That's a notable inconvenience.

How else can this be solved? Am I using Dask wrong?

Note: there's an unanswered dublicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45030651/valueerror-not-all-divisions-are-known-cant-align-partitions-error-on-dask-da).

Answer (score 1):

In the common case you are using, it appears to be that your indexing series is in fact *much* smaller than the source dataframe you want to apply it to. In this case, it makes sense to materialise it and use simple indexing like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ngram': np.random.choice([1, 2, 3], size=1000),
     'other': np.random.randn(1000)})  # fake data
d = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=3)
sizes = d.groupby('ngram').size().compute()
d = d.set_index('ngram')  # also sorts the divisions
ngrams = sizes[sizes > 300].index.tolist()  # a list of good ngrams
d.loc[ngrams].compute()
```